# Why the bad_alloc(const char*) was made private in Visual C++ 2012?

Tags: visual-c++, compatibility, visual-studio-2012

I am just trying to compile a bit bigger project using the Visual Studio 2012 Release Candidate, C++.  The project was/is compiled using the VS2010 now.  (I am just greedy to get the C++11 things, so I tried. :)

Apart of things that I can explain by myself, the project uses the code like this:

```
ostringstream ostr;
ostr << "The " __FUNCTION__ "() failed to malloc(" << i << ").";
throw bad_alloc(ostr.str().c_str());
```

The compiler now complains

```
error C2248: 'std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc' : cannot access private member declared 
    in class 'std::bad_alloc'
```

... which is true.  That version of constructor is now private.

What was the reason to make that version of constructor private?  Is it recommended by C++11 standard not to use that constructor with the argument?

(I can imagine that if allocation failed, it may cause more problems to try to construct anything new.  However, it is only my guess.)

Thanks,
    Petr

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C++11 Standard defines `bad_alloc` as such (18.6.2.1):

```
class bad_alloc : public exception {
public:
    bad_alloc() noexcept;
    bad_alloc(const bad_alloc&) noexcept;
    bad_alloc& operator=(const bad_alloc&) noexcept;
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
};
```

With no constructor that takes a string. A vendor providing such a constructor would make the code using it not portable, as other vendors are not obliged to provide it.

The C++03 standard defines a similar set of constructors, so VS didn't follow this part of the standard even before C++11. MS does try to make VS as standard compliant as possible, so they've probably just used the occasion (new VS, new standard) to fix an incompatibility.

**Edit:** Now that I've seen VS2012's code, it is also clear why the mentioned constructor is left private, instead of being completely removed: there seems to be only one use of that constructor, in the `bad_array_new_length` class. So `bad_array_new_length` is declared a `friend` in bad_alloc, and can therefore use that private constructor. This dependency could have been avoided if `bad_array_new_length` just stored the message in the pointer used by `what()`, but it's not a lot of code anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accustomed to passing a message when you throw a std::bad_alloc, a suitable technique is to define an internal class that derives from std::bad_alloc, and override ‘what’ to supply the appropriate message.

You can make the class public and call the assignment constructor directly, or make a helper function, such as throw_bad_alloc, which takes the parameters (and additional scalar information) and stores them in the internal class.

The message is not formatted until ‘what’ is called.  In this way, stack unwinding may have freed some memory so the message can be formatted with the actual reason (memory exhaustion, bad request size, heap corruption, etc.) at the catch site.  If formatting fails, simply assign and return a static message.

Trimmed example:

(Tip: The copy constructor can just assign _Message to nullptr, rather than copy the message since the message is formatted on demand.  The move constructor, of course can just confiscate it :-).

```
class internal_bad_alloc: public std::bad_alloc
   {
   public:
      // Default, copy and move constructors....

      // Assignment constructor...
      explicit internal_bad_alloc(int errno, size_t size, etc...) noexcept:
         std::bad_alloc()
         {
         // Assign data members...
         }

      virtual ~internal_bad_alloc(void) noexcept
         {
         // Free _Message data member (if allocated).
         }

      // Override to format and return the reason:
      virtual const char* what(void) const noexcept
         {
         if (_Message == nullptr)
            {
            // Format and assign _Message.  Assign the default if the
            // format fails...
            }
         return _Message;
         }

   private:
      // Additional scalar data (error code, size, etc.) pass into the
      // constructor and used when the message is formatted by 'what'...
      mutable char* _Message;
      static  char  _Default[];
   }
};

//
// Throw helper(s)...
//
extern void throw_bad_alloc(int errno, size_t size, etc...)
   {
   throw internal_bad_alloc(errno, size, etc...);
   }
```