# How can I test the portability of a C++ codebase developed and managed in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, standards

I have a very large and very old C++ project currently maintained in Visual Studio 2010. One member of our team has just tested the bumpiness of the upgrade path to VS 2012, and found we were being affected by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133438/why-the-bad-allocconst-char-was-made-private-in-visual-c-2012), through our use of Microsoft's non-standard extensions to the language.

Is there any tool we can run over our codebase that will tell us how many other non-standard extensions we're using, so we can eliminate them before they cause us any more problems?

Comment: Have you checked the compiler options? In many cases you can disable extensions in the old compiler and see where it fails.

Comment: My advice is to always use at least two compilers, preferable more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the compiler switch [`/Za`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fwkeyyhe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which disables extensions.

For example, the following code:

```
#include <string>

void f(std::string&) {}

int main()
{
    f(std::string("hello"));
}
```

Compiles (with warning) when `/Za` is not specified but fails to compile when `/Za` is specified with the following error:

> main.cpp(7) : error C2664: 'f' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::string &'
>             with
>             [
>                 _Elem=char,
>                 _Traits=std::char_traits,
>                 _Ax=std::allocator
>             ]
>             A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue