# _THROW_NCEE (std::bad_alloc, NULL) --- C++11

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am currently upgrading projects at work and ran into this problem.

This code was used to throw a bad_alloc exception if there is not enough space to hold more objects via:

```
    ...
else if (((_SIZT)(-1) / _Count) < sizeof (_Ty))
    _THROW_NCEE(std::bad_alloc, NULL);
```

When upgrading this project to vs2012 ( Toolset V110 ) I get the error:

`error C2248: 'std::bad_alloc': cannot access private member declared in calss 'std::bad_alloc'`

I've read quite a few posts on this but they were using a different method to access this private member. I was wondering if there was a workaround to throw this exception, a different exception I can throw, or a fancy way to access this private class member.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/Ix2jeR)

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without knowing what the macro `_THROW_NCEE` does. And every single one of the identifiers in your code is [reserved by for your standard library implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924243/are-identifiers-starting-with-an-underscore-reserved-according-to-the-latest-c)

Comment: `#define _THROW_NCEE(x, y) throw x(y)`

This is the definition of _THROW_NCEE... I've found other people asking about it, it must have been a popular way to perform this task.

Comment: More specifically, at least in MSVC 2010, `_THROW_NCEE(x, y)` is defined in `<xstddef>`; it's `throw x(y)` if `_HAS_EXCEPTIONS_` is defined, or `x(y)._Raise()` if it isn't.  Can't check any more recent versions at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `_THROW_NCEE` macro, which insists on constructing the exception with a pointer argument. As [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133438/why-the-bad-allocconst-char-was-made-private-in-visual-c-2012), `std::bad_alloc` being constructed from a `const char *` was never standard and was removed in Visual C++ 2012.

To resolve the problem, simply replace `_THROW_NCEE(std::bad_alloc, NULL)` with `throw std::bad_alloc()`.

Comment: That's the post I "studied" most. I just wasn't sure if the throw std::bad_alloc() would be the way to replace this, I wasn't sure about the _THROW_NCEE. However, this worked! So thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3662475 Since `std::bad_alloc` can only be default-constructed or copy-constructed, there is no **other** way to throw it except as `throw std::bad_alloc()`! Another thing to check is that `_THROW_NCEE(a, b)` really only expands to `throw a(b)`, but you already checked that, so you should be fine. It is possible that at a previous time `_THROW_NCEE` was used to make throws optional and thus support exception-free compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because the VS standard library implementation provides this (non-standard) `private` constructor for `std::bad_alloc`. It's possible that this constructor was not private in a previous version.

```
private:
  bad_alloc(const char *_Message) _THROW0()
  : exception(_Message, 1)
  { // construct from message string with no memory allocation
  }
```

The `std::exception` constructor being called is also non-standard. The VS implementation is (in)famous for providing all these constructors.

```
exception();
explicit exception(const char * const &);  // non-standard
exception(const char * const &, int);      // non-standard
exception(const exception&);
```

The only standard constructors defined for `std::bad_alloc` are

```
bad_alloc() noexcept;
bad_alloc(const bad_alloc&) noexcept;
```

So to fix your code, replace

```
_THROW_NCEE(std::bad_alloc, NULL);
```

with

```
throw std::bad_alloc();
```